# What is the difference between total derivative and gradient?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Both gradient and total derivative are a collection or combination of the partial derivatives with respect to each input variable?

Comment: Which definition of total derivative are you using? You probably need to introduce further context than the needed for the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total derivative of a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ is the $m\times n$ matrix of first partial derivatives.  The gradient is defined on functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.  It is the $1\times n $ vector of partial derivatives.  So you could say that the total derivative consists in the matrix whose rows are the gradients of the coordinate functions.  (Hope I got my $m$'s and $n$'s in the right places!)

Comment: With how you have it set up, wouldn't the Jacobian be thought of as the rows being the gradients? The Jacobian itself would be a "column" of gradients.

Comment: Great catch.   You're probably right.  @vb628

Answer (score 2):

Given a function $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, the total derivative is the matrix of partial derivatives, and the gradient is another name for the total derivative in the case $m=1$. if $m > 1$, there is no gradient.